# How to use google speech-to-text on web

Tags: java

I want to create speech-to-text web page like an sample of google speech-to-text that works on the web using Google speech-to-text.

Google speech-to-text sample : https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/?hl=en

I tried using the sample code provided by Google.
This code works well with localhost, but there are the following errors in the ibm cloud:

No line matching interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 16000.0 Hz, 16 bit, mono, 2 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.

I don't know how to solve this error.

```
ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responseObserver = null;

  try (SpeechClient client = SpeechClient.create()) {

    responseObserver =
        new ResponseObserver<StreamingRecognizeResponse>() {
          ArrayList<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses = new ArrayList<>();

          public void onStart(StreamController controller) {}

          public void onResponse(StreamingRecognizeResponse response) {
            responses.add(response);
          }

          public void onComplete() {
            for (StreamingRecognizeResponse response : responses) {
              StreamingRecognitionResult result = response.getResultsList().get(0);
              SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
              System.out.printf("Transcript : %s\n", alternative.getTranscript());
            }
          }

          public void onError(Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t);
          }
        };

    ClientStream<StreamingRecognizeRequest> clientStream =
        client.streamingRecognizeCallable().splitCall(responseObserver);

    RecognitionConfig recognitionConfig =
        RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
            .build();
    StreamingRecognitionConfig streamingRecognitionConfig =
        StreamingRecognitionConfig.newBuilder().setConfig(recognitionConfig).build();

    StreamingRecognizeRequest request =
        StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setStreamingConfig(streamingRecognitionConfig)
            .build(); // The first request in a streaming call has to be a config

    clientStream.send(request);
    // SampleRate:16000Hz, SampleSizeInBits: 16, Number of channels: 1, Signed: true,
    // bigEndian: false
    AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(16000, 16, 1, true, false);
    DataLine.Info targetInfo =
        new Info(
            TargetDataLine.class,
            audioFormat); // Set the system information to read from the microphone audio stream

    if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(targetInfo)) {
      System.out.println("Microphone not supported");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    // Target data line captures the audio stream the microphone produces.
    TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(targetInfo);
    targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
    targetDataLine.start();
    System.out.println("Start speaking");
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    // Audio Input Stream
    AudioInputStream audio = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);
    while (true) {
      long estimatedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
      byte[] data = new byte[6400];
      audio.read(data);
      if (estimatedTime > 60000) { // 60 seconds
        System.out.println("Stop speaking.");
        targetDataLine.stop();
        targetDataLine.close();
        break;
      }
      request =
          StreamingRecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
              .setAudioContent(ByteString.copyFrom(data))
              .build();
      clientStream.send(request);
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
  }
  responseObserver.onComplete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import all needed access keys to your system environment?
Google did not allow just to call their API's without API keys.
You can find how to add API to the environment here
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys